# Prevent User From Entering Characters After a Suffix in a Text Field in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I want the user to only write before a suffix. How can I do that in SWT ?

Something like:

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String SUFFIX = "end";
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setText(SUFFIX);
        text.addVerifyListener(new VerifyListener() {

            @Override
            public void verifyText(VerifyEvent e) {
                // if e.text is after SUFFIX
                // e.doit = false;

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother putting the suffix in the text field at all? Just display it in a label after the text or something like that.

Comment: Yes but the idea was to put the suffix per default so that the user can write just before and if it is at the end to block the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```java
   text.addVerifyListener(event -> {
      // Get the result text of the edit

      StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder(text.getText());

      String newText = event.text != null ? event.text : "";

      buff.replace(event.start, event.end, newText);

      // Allow if result still ends with suffix

      event.doit = buff.toString().endsWith(SUFFIX);
    });
```

Comment: Yes it is a good idea to replace i'll try to go that way. Thank you.